# 400 Bad Request when checkout with Amazon 3.0.10 in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, amazon, amazon-payment

i updated Amazon extention 3.0.10, when click checkout, this show error

```
400 Bad Request
The domain on which you are using the JavaScript SDK has not been 
whitelisted for your application. Please add your website domain 
in the 'Allowed JavaScript Origins' section under 'Web Settings' 
on the Amazon Seller Central App Console for Login with Amazon.
```

I have account amazon, how to add my website domain in Allowed Javascript Origins ? I can not find it.

[image]

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the right email for login in Seller Central? The dropdown on top indicates that you are using a Marketplace Seller Central account.

For Amazon Pay, you have to register and login (different email!) with a separate Seller Central account. Then you will see the whitelisting for the URLs under "Login with Amazon" in the dropdown.